# UISearch bar showing arabic Results

Tags: ios, xcode5, uisearchbar, arabic

I have a UISearch bar that i want it to search through an array of arabic words. But considering that the arabic alphabet is really big and has lots of special cases , for example :

When the user writes the letter ا , the search bar should show the words containing ا and أ

When the user writes the letter و  , the search bar should show him the words containing و and ؤ

When the user writes the letter ى , the search bar should show him the words containing ى and ي and ى

As a test, i did the following :

```
NSString *Alef = @"ا";
```

and in the TextDidChange function i did the following :

```
if([text isEqualToString:Alef]){

        text = @"أ";
        }
```

It worked perfectly, but it's neither logical nor normal to statically define all the different combinations possible, Is there any better way ?

Comment: I think you should use NSPredicate for this. Then you can use CONTAINS[d] for check all similar chars.